# Using shared security group between VPC and EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am new to AWS, need gurus help !

### Question 1:

I need to understand the purpose of having independent security groups created for your VPC and EC2 instance. I have read AWS recommends having independent groups created but I do not understand the conviction behind it.

### Question 2:

Will having independent security group filter out my incoming traffic at the VPC layer and deny requests for which rules have not been defined.

### Question 3:

Consider I have two security groups,

Security Group - EC2 - Inbound Rules to allow SSH and ICMP traffic
Security Group - VPC - No inbound rules configured.

Will I be able to connect to the EC2 instance even though my VPC has no security groups defined ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Could you copy the link where amazon suggests using both ec2-classic security groups and a vpc-ec2 security group?

Comment: Two references:

Comment: @rtrigoso All new AWS accounts are automatically on the EC2-VPC platform so you do not have the choice to launch instances into EC2-Classic if you are a new customer. I do not have choice to launch EC2-Classic instances. Coming to your request, the recommendation was inherited from AWS white paper https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/AWS_Security_Whitepaper.pdf (Page 39). I am not sure how old is this document.

Comment: looks like this paper refers to EC2-Classic security groups and VPC-EC2 security groups. The document was printed in 2017 but it relates to ec2-classic as well. Let me just reply with an answer

Answer (score 3):

AWS offers only two types of security groups:

- VPC-EC2 Security Groups
- EC2-Classic Security Groups

EC2-Classic Instances do not live within a VPC so they are not affected by VPC-EC2 Security groups.

The table that you make reference on page 39 of the security [security whitepapers](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/AWS_Security_Whitepaper.pdf) is showing the differences between old services (EC2-Classic and VPN Classic) that are not offered anymore and the current default one (EC2-VPC). In the current format, your security groups are applied, at instance level, to all attached instances. You can enhance security by using Route Tables and Network Access Control Lists at a VPC level.

if your account was created after 2014, there is no need to worry about classic services.

I hope this helps.

EDIT 1:

I want to clarify that security groups work on attached services. So having a security group work on multiple instances is possible. When you attach multiple instances to a security group, you are giving yourself a break from doing multiple security groups with the same rules on different instances. It is a time saver, a safe way to secure connectivity between other services, and an organizational advantage. For example, you can have a security group that allows all incoming http traffic but maybe you just want ssh traffic into a specific instance.

Below is a diagram that helped me understand this better. The VPC security group mentioned below is just another security group to which all instances are attached. It shows that all instances are attached to it. In this particular example, the security group allows for communication between all instances attached to that security group.

you can find the question where this graph came from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/739179/aws-vpc-public-private-subnets-ec2-instance-cannot-reach-rds-instance)
Check out my third source. It has a nice graph for security groups.

[image: VPC]

Sources:

1. [Moving away from ec2-classic - dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/moving-from-ec2-classic-to-vpc)
2. [Amazon EC2 and Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html#differences-ec2-classic-vpc)
3. [Security Groups vs Network Access Control Lists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Security.html)

Comment: Since security group act as a layer of defense for any traffic coming at the instance level and every instance can have its own security group, what is the purpose of having a default security group created during creation of a VPC when it servers no purpose. Also traffic at subnet level is filtered using NACL which inturn has no relation with the security groups.